# 0 Rows Affected on UPDATE statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have an update statement where I am trying to reduce the quantity for the meta_key quantity from anything above 3 to 3 (the meta_value) and whenever I execute this I get "0 rows affected".

```
UPDATE usermeta 
INNER JOIN cov on cov.user_id = usermeta.user_id 
SET usermeta.meta_value = '3'
WHERE usermeta.meta_key = 'quantity' 
  AND usermeta.meta_value > '3'
  AND cov.end_date = '2017-05-18'
-- this is the query to see the rows I want changed   
SELECT cov.*, usermeta.meta_value
FROM cov
 INNER JOIN usermeta
    ON     cove.user_id = usermeta.user_id
       AND meta_key = 'quantity'
WHERE cov.end_date = '2017-05-18' and usermeta.meta_value > 3
ORDER BY end_date
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked that there's data in the table which actually meets the criteria for this update?

Comment: yesi have! I made an edit and added a query I use to see the rows I want changed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `'3'` and `3`.  So, I would start with:

```
UPDATE usermeta um INNER JOIN
       cov 
       ON cov.user_id = um.user_id 
    SET um.meta_value = '3'
WHERE um.meta_key = 'quantity' AND
      um.meta_value + 0 > 3 AND
      cov.end_date = '2017-05-18';
```

Comment: if I am using 3 and not '3' in the where to see my rows, then I should also be using no quotes in the set correct? Because that would cause a change also?

Comment: @choloboy . . . In the comparison it makes a difference because the values are converted to numbers.  In the `set` it doesn't make a difference because the integer will be converted to a string.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any issue's with the code as such. Did you make sure that you actually have the values that in the usermeta.meta_value field in the usermeta table that are > 3 ? And second thing would be , is your field meta_value and INT data type ? If yes then you would need '3' here.

```
UPDATE usermeta um INNER JOIN cov 
ON cov.user_id = um.user_id 
SET um.meta_value = 3
WHERE um.meta_key = 'quantity' AND
um.meta_value > 3 AND
cov.end_date = '2017-05-18';
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't, I got the following error:  Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:

Comment: So yes you might need to change it back to '3', Did you check the data type for that field ? Is it varchar or INT ? And also did you check if you do have any values that are greater than 3 in that table ?
 
The comparison is happening on different types and when MySQL compares different datatypes they are cast to DOUBLE internally before comparison. So you can try putting single quote around or cast around to solve the issue.

Comment: longtext is the datatype

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my update wasn't the code. It was because there were duplicate id's in the  userid column. Pin pointing the invalid users and adding them to NOT IN in the WHERE clause fixed my issue.